# Outputting product reference metafield in liquid?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I've got a product with a product reference metafield, and the only information I seem to be able to output is the term 'ProductListDrop'

I'm not able to get any of the title, image etc to output at all.
The field has been filled in, just wondering if I am accessing it wrong below?

```
<p> {{ product.metafields.custom.bundle_bottles.value.title }} </p>
```

Cheers,
Marc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Drop is a term presented to you when you are given an Object to work with, but that Object is not ready for immediate consumption.

Imagine your metafield was a String instead of a list.

```
<p> {{ product.metafields.custom.bundle_bottles.value }} </p>
```

You would see the text value stored in the metafield.

So when you setup your Metafield, what type did you choose? When you save data with your Metafield of Type XYZ, what does that data look like?

Without knowing what you saved your data as, it is hard to know why Shopify is informing you of a Drop instead of actual data.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The metafield type is a "Product Reference" and the data in the interface is just a connection to a specific product.

Comment: Then you should just access the value, which is a reference, and see what that contains. If it contains a product, then you know what to do.